# Probability Theory - $0$ doesn't appear among $k$ digits chosen randomly?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What’s the probability that $0$ doesn’t appear among $k$ digits
chosen independently and uniformly at random?

My thinking is that the sample space should be something, say $x$, to the power of $k$ and the event that $0$ doesn't appear is $x-1$ to the power $k$. I am not sure if this is the correct way to think about this. And what the '$x$' should be here.

I saw a solution which says it should be $9^k / 10^k$. But I did not understand how this is.

It would be great if I could get an explanation for this.

Comment: There are $9$ non-zero digits.  The number of ways of selecting $k$ non-zero digits is then $9\times 9\times \cdots \times 9 = 9^k$, seen by [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Similarly, there are $10$ digits and the number of ways of selecting $k$ digits is $10\times 10\times \cdots \times 10=10^k$.  Noting that each selection is equally likely to occur we have that taking the ratio of these gives the probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we're working in base ten, the digits in question are $0, 1, 2, ..., 9$.

Suppose we take a group of $k$ digits, $d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,...,d_k$.

What is the probability that $d_1 \neq 0$? There are $10$ possible digits, and only $1$ is $0$. Thus, $P(d_1 \neq 0) = 9/10$.

Similarly, you can say the same for $d_2, d_3, d_4$, and so on: the rationale is the same.

The probability any $d_i$ having a certain value is independent from that of any other $d_j, i\neq j$ as well. Thus, the probability of each being nonzero is multiplied together, since they're independent. Thus, for example,

$$P(d_1,d_2 \neq 0) = 9/10 \cdot 9/10 = (9/10)^2$$

$$P(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4 \neq 0) = 9/10 \cdot 9/10 \cdot 9/10 \cdot 9/10 = (9/10)^4$$

The pattern should then be clear:

$$P(d_1, d_2, ..., d_k \neq 0) = (9/10)^k = 9^k/10^k$$